# Will Server-Sent Events or SignalR perform better?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Putting aside for the moment the fact that IE doesn't support SSE, if there's a large number of clients, are Server-Sent Events or SignalR going to perform better?

Comment: SO discourages "which is best" questions. Voting to close.

Comment: It is legitimate question to ask which is better for a specific case

Comment: Good Lord, people. This is a perfectly legitimate question to ask (even though the questioner is misunderstanding exactly what SignalR is). If we're not allowed to ask questions about the relative performance, scalability and suitability of different technologies, then WTF is StackOverflow for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to bear in mind is that, under the hood, SignalR will default to the best available method of sending/receiving data e.g. Ajax long polling, server side events, web sockets.

The decision is based on attributes such as the browser in use, plus the web server (e.g. IIS8 has support for web sockets, so SignalR will use those if also the user's browser supports it). What I'm saying is that, SignalR can support many ways of creating a connection, there is no one way available. If you use server side events, then SignalR can also use them, or the next best thing which is web sockets.

So to say which is best isn't a fair question in hindsight.

EDIT: Extract from [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/real-time-web-enablement-with-signalr-in-.net-part-i.htm):

> Though SignalR tries to choose the "best" connection supported by the
>   server and client...

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into comparison, but at least, Rick Strahl is amazed by the performance of SignalR, being unable to overload it even though he's sending several hundred messages a second:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/May/22/A-first-look-at-SignalR